# Replace Multiple Instances of Characters in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function, replace, excel-formula

I have the following formula that I want to convert to a function in VBA.

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(B1,(FIND(",",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"(",","),"-",","),"/",","))-1)),SUBSTITUTE(B1,".", ""))
```

I've tried a few things, but just can't get it to work correctly. 
[Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG8El.jpg)

```
Function CharacterSwap(text)

Dim Old As Variant
Dim Comma As Variant

Old = Array(")", "(", "-", "/")
Comma = Array(",", ",", ",", ",")

For i = LBound(Old) To UBound(Comma)


    If InStr(1, text, Old(i), vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then

        CharacterSwap = Replace(text, Old(i), Comma(i), 1, 1, vbBinaryCompare)

    End If


Next i

End Function

Function SCRUB(text)

If InStr(1, CharacterSwap(text), ",", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then


SCRUB = Left((CharacterSwap(text)), InStr(1, (CharacterSwap(text)), ",") - 1)

Else

SCRUB = text

End If
End Function
```

Comment: also this array formula will do what you want: `=LEFT(B1,MIN(FIND({"(",")","-","/",","},B1&"()-/,"))-1)`  confirm with Ctrl-shift-Enter instead of Enter.

Answer (score 1):

You can also accomplish this in VBA using Regular Expressions.
If I understand you correctly, you want to replace any/all characters in the set of `()/-` within a string with a comma.

```
Option Explicit
Function CharacterSwap(S As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = "[()/-]"
    .Global = True
    CharacterSwap = .Replace(S, ",")
End With

End Function
```

If you should happen to add characters to the character class in `.Pattern` above, you should be aware the that dash `-` must either be the first or last character listed in the class.

If it is anywhere else, it will be interpreted as indicating a range of characters bounded by the preceding and following characters.

In other words

- `[0-9]` would include all of the digits.
- `[-09]` would include only the `dash`, `0` and `9`

Answer (score 0):

```
Function CharacterSwap(text)

Dim Old As Variant
Dim Comma As Variant

Old = Array(")", "(", "-", "/")
Comma = Array(",", ",", ",", ",")

For i = LBound(Old) To UBound(Old)
    If InStr(1, text, Old(i), vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
        'adjust the text in the text variable to maintain the changes
        text = Replace(text, Old(i), Comma(i), 1, 1, vbBinaryCompare)
    End If
Next i

CharacterSwap = text

End Function

Function SCRUB(text)
Dim newtext As String
'put output into a variable to avoid the multiple calls
newtext = CharacterSwap(text)

If InStr(1, newtext, ",", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
    SCRUB = Left(newtext, InStr(1, newtext, ",") - 1)
Else

SCRUB = text

End If
End Function
```

---

But this simple function will do all that in fewer lines:

```
Function Scrub(text)
With Application
    Scrub = Left(text, .Min(.Find(Array("(", ")", "-", "/", ","), text & "()-/,")) - 1)
End With
End Function
```